# Disable FTP upload overwrite on server

Tags: ftp

I have created 1 ftp server for local and external use with live ip. Now I want to configure permission in such a way that user can upload and download files from my share but when they retry to upload same file again it should not get overwrite, instead it should upload that file as another file. (i.e in share i have 1 file named abc when someone tries to upload file name with abc it should not overwrite my original file either it should keep new abc file as abc.copy or abc(1) etc etc.) and no one should be able to delete or modify anything from my share.